# Using Python to get / read the font used in geometry nodes 'String to Curves' node

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

How can I get / read the **font** used in the *String to Curves* node using Python?

**Example:**

The output I'm trying to get back from the image below would be **wmcorners2 Regular**:

[image: Image 1]

I know I can get a value using the code below, but how can I do this for the *String to Curves* node?

```
import bpy

# Get the node
node = bpy.data.materials["MyMaterial"].node_tree.nodes["MyNode"]

# Get the value of the first output
value = node.outputs[0].default_value

print(value)
```

---

The great answer given below by Muzammil and Chris *seems* to get the first font in the list not the currently selected / used font. Is there a workaround or is this a bug?

[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is how you can get it.

```
import bpy

# Reference the node group
geometry_node = bpy.data.node_groups['Geometry Nodes']

# Reference the String to Curves node
curve_node = geometry_node.nodes['String to Curves']

# Get the font
font = curve_node.font
print(font)
# Get the font name
print(font.name)
```

Comment: This seems to get the first font in the list not the currently selected / used font is there a workaround or is this a bug?  See image in question.  Should this be another question?

Comment: @Still seems to be a problem on your end, I just tested and it does work correctly. Please make sure the node you're fetching matches the exact name in the code. If you have more than one "String to Curves" node in your GN tree, the second one will be automatically renamed `String to Curves.001` for example