# Using python to get / read the font used in Geometry Nodes String To Curves Node bug?

Tags: python, geometry-nodes

Getting the currently selected font

**This code seems to get the first font in the list **not the currently selected / used font** is there a workaround or is this a bug? See image.**

The Code:

```
import bpy
#reference the node group
geometry_node = bpy.data.node_groups['Geometry Nodes']

#reference the String to Curves node
curve_node = geometry_node.nodes['String to Curves']

#get the font
font = curve_node.font
print(font)
#get the font name
print(font.name)
```

**Original question:**
[Using python to get / read the font used in Geometry Nodes String To Curves Node](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/284605/using-python-to-get-read-the-font-used-in-geometry-nodes-string-to-curves-node)

[image: img1]

It should comeback with **wmcorners2 Regular** but it comes back with **Alien Lines symbol**

**Update: Response to @lemon**

**I have multiple string to curve nodes for testing but they aren't connected.**

[image: img2]

Comment: for me, this code is doing well. I don't have what you describe. Are you sure you have only one "string to curves" in the node tree?

Comment: @lemon I have multiple nodes for testing but they aren't connected added image above.

Comment: @Gorgious that was my original question which got answered but found a strange issue with it.  I thought I needed to ask another question since that one was answered.

Comment: connected or not they are in the node tree. loop over the nodes and get the ones that are of type 'STRING_TO_CURVES', print their name and font.

Comment: @lemon ok, so what I'm getting is that even though the nodes aren't connected to the "main" tree, python still picks it up.

Comment: @Still: what about providing your blend file, so we can check it out ourselves?

Comment: @Chris,  ok I'll get rid of the stuff not needed and show only the issue and upload it.

Comment: "python still picks it up": of course, this is why unconnected nodes are still available when you save and reload a blend file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to **@lemon and @Chris**

I was cleaning the nodes up to show just the issue and getting reading to post the blend file and I had several more String To Curves nodes way off to the side (**not connected**) and one of them was causing the issue.  I thought if it wasn't connected to the "**main**" node tree Blender and python would ignore it **(not the case)**.  **If the node is there (even if it's not connected) python sees it**.  I just posted this update in case the next person runs into an issue like this.  I'm still learning....